# Android TabHost

Tags: android, android-widget, android-tabhost

I want to make an Tab Activity.
which consists of 3 tabs.
but when i create an project with Android 2.2 and API 8 then in Main.XML its showing an null pointer exception.
but when i change it to API 4 or 5 den it is showing the layout of tabs.

and one more thing i want to clarify is when we create an project we need to specify Build target and AVD on which we want to run application. i want to ask that both the API will be same or can be different??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please add your xml file to your post, this will help answering you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build target version specifies which version of AVD emulator will be launched unless one is already running on that version.
SDK version is for compatibility with various android versions. You can keep the SDK version lower like 5 or 6 unless you are using special API code that is not found in older versions. Also that enables you to deploy to users of devices running on android version 1.6 or so.
I have apps with Tab Activity running on SDK versions 4 and up with no issues on my emulators. However some users are complaining about FC on 2.2.